# I upgraded to Lion. Where's my TRIM support?

Tags: macos, ssd

I upgraded to Lion a couple of weeks ago, looking forward to the promised TRIM support on my 2009 MacBook Pro. It seems that the upgrade hasn't enabled it. There doesn't seem to be any way of doing so in the disk manager. Am I missing something?

[image: My non-TRIMmed SSD]

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.hardmac.com/news/2011/03/27/the-universal-solution-to-activate-trim

Comment: @freerangemonkey: Welcome to Ask Different. Whilst your comment may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Maybe your SSD doesn't support TRIM (even though it's from Apple).

Comment: I called Apple support and it turns out that the SSD does not support TRIM. Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you booted into recovery mode and try "repair disk" using Disk Utility to ensure updated drivers on the SSD? It should have happened at installation, but several lion installs silently failed to make even a Recovery HD for me.

It's a guess, but I could see Disk Utility perhaps correcting that oversight.

I would certainly open a ticket with [Apple Care](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) - you get 90 days of phone support with any purchase and can even schedule a call back from the web site I linked. It might initially warn you about pay per incident, but later on you can select this exemption:

[image]